# aws simple email service not working with godaddy hosting asp.net

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ses, godaddy-api

I was earlier using godaddy email services to send emails from my web application in asp.net. But now I moved to aws ses as it is fast.

The thing is in development environment(Local) aws email is working fine and emails are going but when I am deploying it in godaddy server then no email is going. Do I need to do any settings at godaddy server level or it is my code fault? My website is in shared hosting environment. Is it the reason.

Is this related to MX records?

Here is my code

```
        string UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        string EmailFrom = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"];
        string EmailFromDisplayName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFromDisplayName"];
        string EmailFromPwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFromPwd"];
        string EmailBcc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailBcc"];
        bool EmailIsSSL = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailIsSSL"]);
        int EmailPort = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPort"]);
        string EmailHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailHost"];

        //Create the msg object to be sent
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        //Default email message 
        mailMessage.Bcc.Add(EmailBcc);
       


        //Configure the address we are sending the mail from
        MailAddress address = new MailAddress(EmailFrom, EmailFromDisplayName);
        mailMessage.From = address;

        //Loop all to recepients
        foreach(string emailTo in toAddress)
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(emailTo);
        }
        //Loop to add all Bcc addresses...
        foreach (string emailBcc in bccAddress)
        {
            mailMessage.Bcc.Add(emailBcc);
        }
        //Loop to add all CC addresses...
        foreach (string emailCc in ccAddress)
        {
            mailMessage.CC.Add(emailCc);
        }
        //Add attachments...
        foreach (string filePathWithName in relativeFilePathsToBeAttached)
        {
            if (File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePathWithName)))
            {
                Attachment data = new Attachment(
                   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePathWithName),
                   MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                // your path may look like Server.MapPath("~/file.ABC")
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(data);
            }
        }

        mailMessage.Subject = mailSubject;
        mailMessage.Body = mailBody;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml;

        //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = EmailIsSSL;
        client.Host = EmailHost;
        client.Port = EmailPort;

        //Setup credentials to login to our sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
        //NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailFrom, EmailFromPwd);

        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, EmailFromPwd);

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsMailEnabled"].ToString() == "true")
        {
            client.Send(mailMessage);
        }
```

I am getting this error on server
Failure sending mail.System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at TestCookie.ExecuteSendEmail(String mailBody, String mailSubject, List`1 toAddress, List`1 bccAddress, List`1 ccAddress, List`1 relativeFilePathsToBeAttached, Boolean IsBodyHtml)

Comment: What do you mean "no email is going"? Does your code run? Have you run it with the debugger attached? Is an exception thrown? IsMailEnabled?

Comment: On local this working fine and sending emails from here client.Send(mailMessage);. But after deployment not working. Yes code works on local

Comment: Please re-read my comment. I didn't ask anything about local vs non-local. I asked some very specific questions. Please take the time to answer them.

Comment: What do you mean "no email is going"? Email not working/sending Does your code run? Yes it is. Have you run it with the debugger attached? Yes. Is an exception thrown? No. IsMailEnabled? Yes

Comment: If the SMTP client is not throwing an exception, and you're sure it's reached, then something is going on with the mail server. You'll have to look through the logs for it.

Comment: @mason I have added the error also which I got from logs

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with port number. I was using 587 and 25 and it is not working. But when I used 2587 and it worked for me. I don't know how. If someone can explain then that will help.